# Sorting an ArrayList of mobs by their Y value

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, libgdx

I have a game where I have an `ArrayList` of Mobs. Each mob has a position and I want to sort them by their Y value so the lowest mob is rendered last.

I am running LibGDX so the values range from -300 (bottom) to 300 (top).

This is the current setup:

```
Collections.sort(entities, new Comparator<Entity>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entity e1, Entity e2) {
        return String.valueOf(e1.position.y)
                     .compareTo(String.valueOf(e2.position.y));
    }

});

System.out.println("------------------------");
for (Entity e : entities) {
    System.out.println(entities.indexOf(e) + ": " + e.entityID);
    if (e != null) {
        e.draw(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Agree with @PM77-1 that you ask no question, and add to it that you don't need to compare strings if you have doubles

Comment: If you make clear to the reader what question you are asking that will improve your chances of getting a useful reply.  Reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might give you some ideas.

Comment: I solved it thanks to @Pshemo, I converted them to strings because I didnt know how to compare doubles, as Pshemo pointed out strings sort didnt really work out as they sort in alphabetic order..

Comment: Just a remark : comparing doubles is math... `Double.compare` is just a shortcut, but the logic of this method is completely trivial. If you think about it properly, you will see you should not have blocked on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String.valueOf(e1.position.y).compareTo(String.valueOf(e2.position.y))
```

will convert `y` values of your `e1.position` and `e2.position` to String, and then `compareTo` from string is using alphabetic order.

If `y` is numeric value like `int` and you want to sort it using numeric order you should use

```
Integer.compare(e1.position.y, e2.position.y)
```

BTW having public fields is bad practice which violates encapsulation. You should make them private and add [getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters).

Also since Java 8 we can make our live easier and create comparator using lambdas like

```
Comparator.comparingInt((Entity e) -> e.position.y)
```

or

```
Comparator.<Entity>comparingInt(en -> en.position.y);
```

Comment: Why not just `(e2.position.y - e1.position.y)`?  (OP stated descending order).

Comment: @PM77-1 to avoid potential integer overflow. Not that it could happen here, but for  big values it could be a problem. That is why it is better to get used to `Integer.compare`.

Comment: the position is a LibGDX Vector2 so it's not my code